# Where and how to place key value pairs in an HTTP request using Retrofit? (Without breaking HTTP standards)

Tags: android, rest, http, retrofit, retrofit2

In the case of a classic username and password account authentication process in an android app., there are multiple ways that I can accomplish this:

1. Place the username and password fields as HTTP headers. (Easiest using Retrofit annotations)
2. Create a Hashmap and place the username and password in it, then pass the hashmap in the HTTP body. (Introducing some boilerplate code)
3. Create a POJO class and add attributes for the username and password, then pass this object in the body using GSON serialization. (In my opinion, this is too much unnecessary boilerplate code overall in our case here)

My question is, what is the best practice according to standards to accomplish such REST calls using Retrofit, without breaking HTTP standards or making the code look dirty or over-engineered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Basic authentication.

The common practice in REST architecture is to use the Authorization header like that :
`Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Beware to not allow `:` in the password or username or to url-encode them !